How to Remove the Splash Screen in Flutter?
Is it possible to remove or hide the default splash screen provided by the system?
I have created a splah screen with flutter but default one i can't remove it
here is the code:
import 'package:educationalapp/Screens/Wellcome.dart';
import 'package:educationalapp/values/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Navigate to the Home screen after 5 seconds
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const WellcomePage()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: mainColor,
        ),
        child: const Center(
          child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I’m trying to add a Flutter package to my project and was wondering about the best approach to do this. Specifically, I would like to add a package without going through the full dependency management process.
Here’s what I’ve tried:
i add flutter_native_splash package but i does not add animations that you all knows
and also flutter_animated_splash that will also show default splash screen

flutter_native_splash replaces the mandatory still image with a different mandatory still image. You cannot do anything to make this time period longer or shorter. This image is shown while your app is loading and being prepared, and is being shown before your app starts "running" at main().
So no, you cannot remove this time period, but you can pick what static image to show.
You can be slick, and have an animation that starts from the static image, and then animates to some other image or series of items.  You would launch that at the beginning of main().

Thanks,
I know how to remove the default splash screen in Flutter but can’t get it to work.
Here's the method I tried: link
